# Look at center of an image with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I'm stuck in a problem.
I have a image on a website that has usually a larger width than the screen. What I want to do is to move this image so that you always look on the center, even if youre resizing the browser.

code like this:

```
    .center {
      position: relative;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }

<img class="center" src="picture.jpg">
```

does not help.

I cant find a proper solution. Using the image as CSS background would not help, as I want to change the images dynamically.

Is it even possible to do this with CSS? Or should I use JavaScript?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: you can change the background of an element dynamically too

Comment: Is the image static? In other words will the dimensions of the image change?

Comment: The width will be always the same - height is varying from image to image

Answer (score 3):

Use a background image. You can change that not only with CSS (pseudo :hover), but also (and more effectively) with JavaScript.

```
.center {
    background: transparent url('/path/to/image') center center no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.center:hover {
    background: transparent url('/path/to/another/image') center center no-repeat;
}
```

JavaScript (jQuery)

```
$('.center').css('background-image','url(/path/to/image)');
```

Comment: What if he already has a bg image? This is a bad hack. Use a standard method like body width 100%

Comment: Thanks you! Width and height at 100% will just stretch the image over the whole browser size if I use it with an image tag. Using `auto` reverses this but still does not help to look at the center of the image.

Comment: setting width and height to 100% will not stretch the image. the image will remain centered.  To stretch the image you have to set the background-size to 100%

Comment: Okay, as far as I can see, it is working properly with the code above if I use it in a body-style. Using it as a class in some other element does not give me a view to the center. I'll try to change the body-background with JS.

Answer (score 0):

What about using Top:50% and Left:50% in your CSS to position to the middle of the image?

Comment: It would still be off. To center it like that, you would need to do: `top: 50% - (image width / 2)` and `left: 50% - (image width / 2)`. While this can be accomplished with JavaScript, it cannot with CSS alone.

Answer (score 0):

Bit late to the party but I think this is what you want:

```
.center {
    position:absolute;
    top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}
```